# Why I can't increment my variable in this tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to make a programme to improve mental calculation with an gui with tkinter. And I apologies in advance if I my errors are really stupid, but it's the first time I use tkinter.

So I have the function addition which gives me two numbers (a,b) and the sum of these two number (c).
The user enters the result in the entry, but the problem is that when I try to verify if the result is the good one, I want to add +1 at the general score if it's the good answer in the function getEntry.

(By the way, I don't know if it's a good this to do the verification in the same function that I get the entry. I will be much easier for me to use a return at the end of the function and then use an other one but if I use a return in my function I don't know how to receive the value that I return in a variable because I call the function thanks to the button...)

I need to increment the variable for the score but I can't and I don't why...

I use the built-in function global for the function score because it's not in the function getEntry(). But when I click on the button to verify my answer, I have this error message

```
line 96, in getEntry
    score= score +1
NameError: name 'score' is not defined
```

I test with a really basic program:

```
x=0
def fonc():
    global x
    x=x+1
fonc()
print(x)
```

And it print 1
So I don't understand why it doesn't work in my big program...

Here is my code:

```
class PageAdd1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.id = controller.id

        lblTitle = tk.Label(self, text="Mode Addition Facile") 
        lblTitle.pack()

        btnBack = tk.Button(self, text="Revenir à la sélection de la difficulté",
                            command=lambda: controller.up_frame("PageAdd"))
        btnBack.pack()
        score=0

        def getEntry():
            global score
            res=int(entryRes.get())
            if res == c:
                score= score +1
            print(score)

        a, b, c = addition(1)
        lstQuestion = ["Quelle est le résultat de l'oppération ", str(a), " + ", str(b), "?"]
        question = "".join(lstQuestion)
        lblQuestion = tk.Label(self, text=question)
        lblQuestion.pack()

        res=tk.IntVar()
        entryRes= tk.Entry(self, textvariable= res)
        entryRes.pack()

        btnValid = tk.Button(self, text= "Valider",command=getEntry)
        btnValid.pack()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Your `score` is a local to the `__init__` function.  It's not a global.  You either need to make `score` a true global, by moving it outside of the class, or use `nonlocal` instead of `global`.

Comment: One might ask why you want this to be a global.  Why not make it `self.score`, and then have a method to return the current score?  Globals are evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`score=0` is a local variable in `__init__`. You need to add `global score` to  `__init__` as well:

```
class PageAdd1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # ...
        global score
        score=0

        def getEntry():
            global score
            res=int(entryRes.get())
            if res == c:
                score= score +1
            print(score)
```

Alternatively, since you have a class, you could make everything members of the class:

```
class PageAdd1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # ...
        self.score=0
        # ...
        btnValid = tk.Button(self, text= "Valider",command=self.getEntry)
        btnValid.pack()

    def getEntry(self):
        res=int(entryRes.get())
        if res == c:
            self.score= self.score +1
        print(self.score)
```

Comment: It works with the global in the init, thank you very much !